# zf2 - best way to create a common form span across all the page of the website?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am a total beginner in zf2 and has no experience on previous zend frameworks at all, so may be a basic question,

i have search form (this is a quick search form) spans across all the pages of the website. So my confusion is how do i develop it (i think this more of a widget in other frameworks but since zend dont have widget concept, i am wondering

1. is this logic should be coded as Zend Helper class ?
2. or is the logic should be considered as ZendForm class ?  if so can we create 
   partial forms ? to be included in the main layout page
3. Where should the HTML part go ?i.e to the layout.phtml or to the /view/ as a partial
   rendering file or should it goto the generating class it self ?
4. how to i render the search results in AJAX into a Content Area DIV without loading
   the full page again and again ?

any ideas on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you just code the `Form` as if it would be a totally normal Form. It should belong into `YourModule\src\YourModule\Form\`-Namespace. There will be no differences in creating the Form per-sé.

Next Step for you would be to make this Form available via the ServiceLocator. You do this via configuration inside `Module.php`'s `getServiceConfig()`. Like:

```
getServiceConfig() 
{
    return array( 'factories' => array(
        'MyNamespace\SearchWidgetForm' => 'YourModule\Form\SearchWidgetForm'
    ));
}
```

And last but not least you'll create a ViewHelper to render your form. There's good tutorials for that stuff out there. You'll need to inject the Form into the ViewHelper.

- [Evan Coury on Creating ViewHelpers in ZF2](http://blog.evan.pro/creating-a-simple-view-helper-in-zend-framework-2)
- [Michaël Gallego on Creating Widgetized Content in ZF2](http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2012/10/06/how-to-replace-the-action-helper-in-zf-2-and-make-great-widgetized-content/)

Read the articles in the order given and you'll learn the most ;)